# want to rerun all the tasks even if only one airflow fails

Tags: python, airflow, dbt

```
with DAG('test_project_dbt',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False) as dag:

    task1 = triggerJobOperator('task1', 53592)
    task2 = waitJobRunOperator('task2', 53592)
```

I have two tasks task1 and task2 , I want to rerun all the tasks even if one fails , how can I achieve this
Any help would be highly appreciated